# AWS EFS hang while writing files in Oregon region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

We started seeing some timeout failures in EFS in Oregon region while writing files to it.
In dmesg, the following error shows:

```
nfs: server fs-xxx.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com not responding, timed out
nfs: server fs-xxx.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com not responding, timed out
nfs: server fs-xxx.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com not responding, still trying
```

I tried to `cd` into the mountpoint, but `cd` hang and unable to be stopped via ctrl + c.

But if I create a new mountpoint and mount same efs server, it works.

It's really weird and this issue only shows up recently, it was working smoothly before.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would open a ticket with AWS support - this doesn't sound like something we'll be able to solve for you.

Comment: what is your instance size? How much data per second are your transferring to/from EFS? I think that you are being bandwidth throttled. If true, you will need to pick a large instance size. CloudWatch metrics can help you track performance.

Comment: thank you guys. We don't have support plan but I posted it on AWS developer forum. My instance size is r4.2xlarge, the data transferring is about 10GB, not sure about data speed. I don't think it will be high. I'm watching cloudwatch metrics too but did not see anything unusual. I have tweaked a few settings and will continue watching this issue.

Comment: Your instance size is fine for bandwidth and resources for EFS. Can you repeat the problem on demand? This will help AWS support.

Comment: Check your burst credit balance, and other metrics.  A large load on a small EFS filesystem can result in a slowdown, so it seems conceivable that an extreme cases, timeouts could result.